# You either love him or hate him

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> On my own, I am pale
>   Add something soft and I put you in a hole
>   Add something loud and I take off without fail
>   Add something small and I insult a troll
>   Add the first and I get off the rail
>   Add the second and to spoil is my role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my own, I am pale

> light

Add something soft and I put you in a hole

> p (piano: play music soft) + light → plight

Add something loud and I take off without fail

> f (forte: play music loud) + light → flight

Add something small and I insult a troll

> s (small) + light → slight

Add the first and I get off the rail

> a (first) + light → alight

Add the second and to spoil is my role.

> b (second) + light → blight

Title: You either love him or hate him

> Light Yagami - the protagonist of Death Note. Inspires widely varying response from followers.

Comment: Correct! However, your interpretation of the title is wrong. That's where the knowledge tag comes in. I will let you ponder a bit about the title before accepting this.

Comment: I need a *clue* - maybe a fictional character? Add the fourth and fifth to describe the puzzle!

Comment: Fictional character, yes.

Comment: I'm afraid I may be out of my depth for the title, but looked up and took a go.